# Несколько вопросов по MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте. Подскажите правильно ли я понял эти действия в MVC.

1)Действие Index собирает список фильмов из свойства Movies из экземпляра контекста базы данных:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Movies.ToList());
        }
```

2) Подскажите как лучше описать вот это действие (то что тут происходит):

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var tickets = db.Tickets.Include(t => t.Movie);
            return View(tickets.ToList());
        }
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: [Вы путаете паттерн и схожий по названию фреймворк.]

А вы сами писали код? Почему бы вам не спросить автора кода?

Answer (score 1):

1) берет все фильмы из бд, создает список из них и передает его во View.

2) получает из бд все билеты и связанный с ним фильм. и как в пункте 1. создает список и передает во View